# How to return one container to a clean state in docker compose?

Tags: docker-compose, docker-volume

Using `docker-compose restart <service>` retains some persistent state of the container (e.g. it does not remove database tables from the postgres alpine container, presumably because a persistent volume is defined [somewhere](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/471fee5b7225911a5fdc2c08325ece0c1e488b3b/Dockerfile-alpine.template#L164) inside of that image, even without being mentioned in `docker-compose.yaml`).

Using e.g. `docker-compose down && docker-compose up -d` returns *all* containers to a fresh state.

How do you return just one container to a fresh state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To recreate fresh a single service with docker-compose:

```
docker-compose rm -svf <service> && docker-compose up -d <service>
```

When you remove the container, the `-v` instructs to also evict from storage any anonymous volumes that were attached to it. If you omit this `-v` then you will accumulate unused volumes, and subsequently want to run `docker volume prune` to clean those up. The `-s` is just a shortcut instead of typing `docker-compose stop <service>` beforehand, and `-f` avoids prompting to confirm `yes`.

For comparison, if you merely attempt `docker-compose restart <service>` then any existing anonymous volumes will be maintained (i.e. the process will be rebooted but internal stored state of the container can persist). Supposedly `docker-compose build <service> && docker-compose restart <service>` would work if there had been any changes in the source for that container.

A more concise alternative is:

`docker-compose up -V -d <service>`

This *does* recreates a particular service, even if the services were already up; the `-V` (which can also be expressed as `--renew-anon-volumes`) means to create fresh anonymous volumes instead of retrieving those from the pre-existing container. However it leaves the previous volumes stored until subsequent pruning.

Answer (score 0):

The command is:

```
SERVICE=backend && docker compose -f ~/dev/docker/docker-compose.yml down -v ${SERVICE} && docker compose -f ~/dev/docker/docker-compose.yml up -d ${SERVICE}
```

I use it in the alias in `~/.zshrc` (`~/.bashrc`):

```
alias backend_restart='SERVICE=backend && docker compose -f ~/dev/docker/docker-compose.yml down -v ${SERVICE} && docker compose -f ~/dev/docker/docker-compose.yml up -d ${SERVICE}'

alias backend_rebuild='SERVICE=backend && docker compose -f ~/dev/docker/docker-compose.yml down -v ${SERVICE} && docker compose -f ~/dev/docker/docker-compose.yml up --build -d ${SERVICE}'
```

Answer (score -1):

By using `docker-compose down and up` you cannot freshen a single container, but by using `docker-compose restart <service name>` you can restart single service.

Please check compose cli reference : https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/

Comment: This doesn't address the question. How do you recreate fresh the volumes associated with that single service?

Comment: @benjimin you can't recreate single service with docker-compose.

Comment: @Javad, you are wrong. Please, see my comment below.